# How to fill the header when scrolling right?

Tags: html, css

When i re-size my browser and scroll to the right end,
I get the header like the following figure,  http://awesomescreenshot.com/02a29uof91

[This is my output](https://docs.google.com/document/d/133Uek4Fd3G3eB6Zz4CNomPGzARevCUg4fAV4Xhvin-o/edit?pli=1)

Even stackoverflow Header too display like this..

How to fill the header when scrolling right?

CSS

```
    body
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #666;
    background: #fff;
}

#templatemo_header_wrapper
{
    height: 114px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #19446a url(images/templatemo_header_bg.jpg) repeat-x;
}

#templatemo_header
{
    width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#templatemo_menu_wrapper
{
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    height: 41px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: url(images/templatemo_menu_bg.jpg) repeat-x;
}

#templatemo_menu
{
    width: 1320px;
    height: 41px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#templatemo_menu ul
{
    margin: 0 0 0 28px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
}

#templatemo_menu ul li
{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    display: inline;
}

#templatemo_menu ul li a
{
    float: left;
    display: block;
    height: 22px;
    width: 115px;
    padding: 13px 0 0 0;
    background: url(images/templatemo_menu.jpg) bottom no-repeat;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight: bold;
    outline: none;
 }
```

HTML

```
<div id="templatemo_header_wrapper" >
        <div id="templatemo_header">
            <div class="style1">
                <table width="1200px">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align: left">
                                <p>
                                   Heading
                                </p>
                            </td>
                            <td align="right">
                                <table>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <img height="50px" src="images/x.PNG" alt="x">
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <strong><span style="font-family: Times New Roman; text-transform: uppercase; font-size: 18pt;">
                                                  Comapny name</span></strong>
                                                <br>
                                                <span style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal;">Pvt.
                                                    Ltd.</span>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Are you asking a programming question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some code would be helpful.

Genrally, if you want things to fill horizontally, you need to specify a 100% width container and then place (or float) elements within it.

And I don't see anything like this on stackoverflow.com, regardless of how wide I make the window.